# Excel - How to extract a text in a text based on a criteria in the same text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Have been trying to work it out but did not succeed.
I am trying to extract translated data from a Json file and extract the different translated in different columns. Important to know is that the data does not always have the same sequence.

The json looks like this:

{"en":"life","nl-BE":"leven","de-DE":"Leben","fr-BE":"la vie"}

See example in Excel what I would like to achieve.[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69PUx.png)

```
Column A                                                                 Column B Column C Column D Column E
 Json                                                                    "en"    "nl-BE"  "de-DE"   "fr-BE"
{"en":"life","nl-BE":"leven","de-DE":"Leben","fr-BE":"la vie"}           life    leven    Leben   la vie
{"nl-BE":"Kinderen","de-DE":"Kinder","en":"Children","fr-BE":"Enfants"}  Children Kinderen Kinder Enfants
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? This site thrives on feedback. If any worked please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer. If they did not work please let us know what went wrong so we can better the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,":",REPT(" ",99)),",",REPT(" ",99)),FIND(B$1,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,":",REPT(" ",99)),",",REPT(" ",99)))+99,99)),"""",""),"}","")
```

Put it in B2 copy over and down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @ScottCraner 's excellent answer, you could write a UDF in VBA. In a standard code module put:

```
Function JsonExtractor(json As String, key As String) As String
    Dim data As String
    Dim items As Variant
    Dim item As Variant

    data = Trim(json)
    data = Mid(data, 2, Len(data) - 2) 'strip off {,}
    items = Split(data, ",")
    For Each item In items
        If item Like key & ":*" Then
            item = Split(item, ":")(1)
            item = Mid(item, 2, Len(item) - 2) 'strip off ","
            JsonExtractor = item
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next item
    'raise error if not found:
    JsonExtractor = CVErr(xlErrValue)
End Function
```

And then put the formula `=JsonExtractor($A2,B$1)` in B2 and copy:

[image]